# Handle error in SQL Trigger without failing transaction?

Tags: sql, transactions, triggers

I've a feeling this might not be possible, but here goes...

I've got a table that has an insert trigger on it. When data is inserted into this table the trigger fires and parses a long varbinary column. This trigger performs some operations on the binary data and writes several entries into a second table.

What I have recently discovered is that sometimes the binarydata is not "correct" (i.e. it does not conform to the spec it is supposed to - I have NO control over this whatsoever) and this can cause casting errors etc.

My initial reaction was to wrap things in TRY/CATCH blocks, but it appears this is not a solution either, as the execution of the CATCH means the transaction is doomed and I get a "Transaction doomed in trigger" error.

What is imperitive is that the data still gets written to the initial table. I don't care if the data gets written to the second table or not.

I'm not sure if I can accomplish this or not, and would gratefully receive any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you could do is commit a transaction inside a trigger and then perform those cast.
i don't know if that's a possible solution to your problem though.

another option would be to create a function IsYourBinaryValueOK which would check the column value. however the check would have to be done with like to not cause an error.

Comment: Yes this idea worked great - a little function to check each character to see if it is in '1', '2', '3' etc - if at any point it isn't it'll return 0 otherwise it'll return the result of the cast. Seems to do the job nicely!

Comment: @Valerion - you may also want to look at IsNumeric() function, but it may be too lax for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like this code should run in an insert trigger since it is conceptually two different transactions. You would probably be better off with asynchronous processing such as service broker, a background nanny task that looks for 'not done' work, etc. You could also handle it by using a sproc to do the insert in one transaction and then having it call the do-other-work code afterwards.

If you absolutely have to do it in the trigger then you basically need an autonomous transaction. For some ideas see [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/08/22/how-to-create-an-autonomous-transaction-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) (the techniques apply to sql 2005 as well).

Comment: Good link and interesting reading, although I've gone with the other answer. Agreed that with hindsight perhaps a trigger isn't stricly best, but it does fit in better conceptually with the rest of the system and is easier to manage. In the end by using a function I've actually avoided the error being raised in the first place which I think is better than trying to work around it.